# how to update a column containing xml in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, updatexml

I have a table with columns ID, XML where the XML column contains xml string. The xml is in the flowing form:

```
<list>
  <element>
    <key>key</key>
    <value>value</value>
  </element>
...
</list>
```

I need to find and remove all the elements in the xml that contain a certain SPECIFIC_XXX_VALUE for example:

```
<element>
   <key>SPECIFIC_XXX_VALUE</key>
   <value>ANY_VALUE</value>
</element>
```

This elements should be removed from the xml for all the rows in the table.

Comment: Are these values coming from a mysql table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update TABLE set XML = UpdateXML(XML, '//element[key="valueOfKey"]','')  where "%valueOfKey%";